# Listing all bolts in Storm topology

Tags: apache-storm, topology

When I build my topology and receive the `StormTopology`, I would like to be able to list all Spouts and Bolts that have been added. I use the `get_bolts()` (and `get_spouts()`) method, but from there it seems I cannot access the original Spout/Bolt instance.
The only thing I get is the Thrift Bolt object. How do I need to cast to receive my Bolt/Spout impl?

Comment: You can see all of them from storm-ui, not sure it is what you look for though.

Comment: Do you want only list bolts and spouts or what do you want to do exactly with spouts/bolts?

Comment: I'd like to access the java instances that I supply with new MyCustomBolt() in the setBolt() method :) i have some public methods on them I would like to trigger.